# Catch 22 ModuleNotFoundError: ImportError: If I fix one I get the other

Tags: python, setuptools, python-3.8, setup.py

I have a Python project that I am trying to package for PyPI but when I get it working with setup.py it stops working as a standalone script.

The directory structure is like:

```
project_dir
    setup.py
    module_name_dir
        __init__.py
        main.py
        other.py
```

**init**.py exports selected methods from main.py. main.py imports various things from other.py

When I write the imports in main.py like

```
from other import *
```

Then `$ python main.py` runs fine but `$ python setup.py sdist` gives "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'other'"

On the other hand when I write the imports like

```
from .other import *
```

then `$ python setup.py sdist` runs fine but `$ python main.py` gives "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
"

setup.py script is very straightforward, close to the minimal example:

```
from setuptools import setup

description=""" ... """
long_description=""" ... """
    
setup(
    name="",
    version="",
    packages=[module_name],
    url="",
    license='MIT',
    author="",
    author_email="",
    description=description,
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    keywords='',
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Topic :: System :: Networking',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3'
    ],
)
```

I assume this apparent catch 22 situation is because I have dome something wrong and not the way it is actually supposed to be. Can anyone help me fix it?

Comment: can you add your setup.py file?

Comment: @DevanshSingh have added setup.py above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you try to use different module names for the same file.
This will not work.

You want create a package:

The module name of the file `module_name_dir/main.py` is `module_name_dir.main`

If you want to call the script stand alone you could for example type:

`python -m module_name_dir.main`
But you cannot (should not) call it with
`python module_name_dir/main.py`
You should neither cd to `module_name_dir` and call it with `python main.py`

**Concerning entry points:**

This is completely optional, but I thought it might be good to know:

What you could do however is following:

Add an entry to your setup.py.

For example:

```
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'mycmd = module_name_dir.main:main',
            ]
        },
```

This assumes that `module_name_dir/main.py` contains a function named `main`

If you use virtualenvs (which is recommened for developping python packages) you can for testing purposes type
`pip install -e .`

Then you can type mycmd to start your script

Comment: OK. thanks for this explanation. Based on your info, in the PyCharm run configuration settings I changed the spec from the file name to the module name and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to update your setup.py file:

```py
from setuptools import *

description=""" ... """
long_description=""" ... """
    
setup(
    name="",
    version="",
    packages=[module_name],
    url="",
    license='MIT',
    author="",
    author_email="",
    description=description,
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    packages = find_packages(),
    keywords='',
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Topic :: System :: Networking',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3'
    ],
)
```

The `find_packages()` function will add all external modules along with the main .py file, and if it a CLI, then as @KlausF said, you'll have to include an entry point